# D3.js: xScale returns me undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm totally newbie with D3 and I've got a really big problem. I have made a development to show a multibar graphic who works perfectly and you can check here:

[image: Edit MultipleBarChart]

I have copy this development to my application and I've got an error and I don't know why it happends.

This is the code of my application:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import "../../../css/content.css";

const HEIGHT = 360;
let WIDTH = 0;

const OFFSET_TOP = 30;
const OFFSET_BOTTOM = 30;
const OFFSET_LEFT = 80;
const OFFSET_RIGHT = 50;

/**
 * To build this graphic we need to pass some values in these props:
 *      - idContainer: id of the div container. This must be unique
 *      - data: data to build the graphic. This is an array of json objects where each json object has the next structure:
 *              {
 *                  shoot: String with the name of shoot, 
 *                  abrev_home_team: % of shoot for that team, 
 *                  abrev_away_team: % of shoot for that team
 *              }
 *      - groupKey: Name of the key which are goingto use to group the bars
 *      - keys: Array with the strings of all the keys which we are going to group around the groupKey
 *      - y_label: String with the name of Y Axis
 *      - lang: language to use to show the float numbers
 */

let data = [
  {
    name: "SPAR CITYLIFT GIRONA",
    ortg: 95.17,
    drtg: 81.96
  },
  {
    name: "PERFUMERIAS AVENIDA",
    ortg: 109.08,
    drtg: 79.26
  },
  {
    name: "IDK EUSKOTREN",
    ortg: 89.50,
    drtg: 95.13
  },
  {
    name: "QUESOS EL PASTOR",
    ortg: 87.30,
    drtg: 99.58
  },
  {
    name: "VALENCIA B.C.",
    ortg: 93.40,
    drtg: 86.81
  },
  {
    name: "DURÁN MAQUINARIA ENSINO",
    ortg: 93.12,
    drtg: 95.69
  },
  {
    name: "CADI LA SEU",
    ortg: 95.37,
    drtg: 94.97
  },
  {
    name: "RPK ARASKI",
    ortg: 89.50,
    drtg: 88.85
  },
  {
    name: "EMBUTIDOS PAJARIEL BEMBIBRE PD",
    ortg: 81.85,
    drtg: 95.47
  },
  {
    name: "CAMPUS PROMETE",
    ortg: 86.38,
    drtg: 92.29
  },
  {
    name: "CIUDAD DE LA LAGUNA TENERIFE",
    ortg: 88.69,
    drtg: 96.81
  },
  {
    name: "MANN-FILTER CASABLANCA",
    ortg: 85.44,
    drtg: 93.78
  },
  {
    name: "LOINTEK GERNIKA BIZKAIA",
    ortg: 100.12,
    drtg: 85.28
  },
  {
    name: "NISSAN  AL-QÁZERES EXTREMADURA",
    ortg: 81.39,
    drtg: 99.10
  }
];

class MultipleBarChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.props = props;
    this.state = {
      loaded: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     //Don't do anything!!!
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.props = nextProps;

    console.log("OFFSET_TOP: " + OFFSET_TOP);
    console.log("FFSET_BOTTOM: " + OFFSET_BOTTOM);
    console.log("OFFSET_LEFT: " + OFFSET_LEFT);
    console.log("OFFSET_RIGHT): " + OFFSET_RIGHT);



    let data2 = this.props.data.map((item, index) =>{
      let item2 = {};
      item2.name = item.name;
      item2.ortg = parseFloat(item.ortg).toFixed(2);
      item2.drtg = parseFloat(item.drtg).toFixed(2);
      console.log("DATA name: " + typeof data[index].name + " PROPS name: " + typeof item2.name);
      console.log("DATA ortg: " + typeof data[index].ortg.toFixed(2) + " PROPS ortg: " + typeof item2.ortg);     
      console.log("DATA drtg: " + typeof data[index].drtg.toFixed(2) + " PROPS drtg: " + typeof item2.drtg); 
      return item2;
    });

    let canvas = this.setCanvas();
    let colors = this.setColors();
    let scales = this.setScales(data2, this.props.keys);
    //let scales = this.setScales(data, this.props.keys, this.props.groupKey);
    this.setAxis(canvas, scales);
    this.setLegend(canvas, colors, this.props.keys);
    this.setBars(canvas, data2, scales, this.props.keys, colors, this.props.lang, this.props.groupKey);
    //this.setBars(canvas, data, scales, this.props.keys, colors, this.props.lang, this.props.groupKey);
    this.setState({
      loaded: (typeof data2 !== "undefined" && typeof this.props.keys !== "undefined") ? true : false
    });

}

  setAxis(canvas, scales) {
    //x axis
    canvas
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr(
        "transform",
        "translate(" + 0 + ", " + (HEIGHT - OFFSET_TOP - OFFSET_BOTTOM) + ")"
      )
      .call(d3.axisBottom(scales.x0Scale))
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("font-size", "10pt")
      .attr("dx", "-.1em");

    //y axis
    console.log("OFFSET_LEFT: " + OFFSET_LEFT);
    canvas
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      //.call(d3.axisLeft(scales.yScale).ticks(null, ".00%"))
      .call(d3.axisLeft(scales.yScale).tickFormat(d3.format(".2f")))
      //.selectAll("text")
      .style("font-size", "8pt")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + OFFSET_LEFT + ", 0)")
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", OFFSET_LEFT / 2 + 12)
      .attr("y", OFFSET_TOP)
      .attr("dx", "-3em")
      .attr("dy", "-1em")
      .attr("fill", "#FFFFFF")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .style("font-size", "8pt")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(this.props.y_label);

    //return { xAxis: xAxis, yAxis: yAxis };
  }

  setBars(canvas, data, scales, keys, colors, lang, groupKey) {
    let height = HEIGHT - OFFSET_TOP - OFFSET_BOTTOM;
    //var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

    let bar = canvas
      .append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        //return "translate(" + scales.x0Scale(d.shoot) + ",0)";
        console.log("d[groupKey]: " + d[groupKey]);
        console.log("scales1: " + scales.x0Scale(d[groupKey]));
        return "translate(" + scales.x0Scale(d[groupKey]) + ",0)";
      });

    //Here, you append rects to the groups:
    bar
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return keys.map(function(key) {
          return {
            key: key,
            value: d[key]
          };
        });
      })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return scales.x1Scale(d.key);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return scales.yScale(d.value);
      })
      .attr("width", scales.x1Scale.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - scales.yScale(d.value);
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return colors(d.key);
      });

    //Finally, here, you append texts to the groups:
    bar
      .selectAll("text")
      .data(function(d) {
        return keys.map(function(key) {
          return {
            key: key,
            value: d[key]
          };
        });
      })
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("class", "label-multiple-bar")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return scales.x1Scale.bandwidth() * (i + 0.5);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return scales.yScale(d.value) - 5;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return lang === "es"
          ? String(d.value).replace(".", ",") + "%"
          : d.value + "%";
      });
  }

  setCanvas() {
    console.log("WIDTH: " + d3.select("#" + this.props.idContainer).style("width"));
    WIDTH = parseFloat(
      d3.select("#" + this.props.idContainer).style("width")
    ).toFixed(2);
    let svg = d3
      .select("#" + this.props.idContainer)
      .append("svg")
      .style("background-color", "#354560")
      .style("color", "#FFFFFF") //With this we've got the color of the axis too
      .attr("height", HEIGHT)
      .attr("width", WIDTH);

    return svg;
  }

  setColors() {
    return d3
      .scaleOrdinal()
      .range(["#DC3545", "#FFC107", "#007BFF", "#28A745", "#17A2B8", "#cf0eed"]);
  }

  /**
   * Set a legend to the graphic at the top right of it
   *
   * @param {*} canvas
   * @param {*} colors
   * @param {*} keys
   */
  setLegend(canvas, colors, keys) {
    let legend = canvas
      .append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(keys.slice())
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
      });

    legend
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", WIDTH - OFFSET_RIGHT - OFFSET_LEFT)
      .attr("y", 12)
      .attr("width", 25)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .attr("fill", colors);

    legend
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", WIDTH - OFFSET_RIGHT - OFFSET_LEFT + 60)
      .attr("y", 18)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .attr("fill", "#FFFFFF")
      .attr("font-family", "Roboto")
      .style("font-size", "10pt")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end");
  }

  setScales(data, keys, groupKey) {
    let xRange = [OFFSET_LEFT + 0.05, WIDTH - OFFSET_RIGHT];
    let yRange = [HEIGHT - OFFSET_TOP - OFFSET_BOTTOM, OFFSET_TOP];

    let x0 = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(
        data.map(function(d) {
          return d[groupKey];
        })
      )
      .rangeRound(xRange)
      .paddingInner(0.2);

    let x1 = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(keys)
      .rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()])
      .padding(0);

    var y = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([
        0,
        d3.max(data, function(d) {
          return d3.max(keys, function(key) {
            return parseFloat(d[key]);
          });
        })
      ])
      .nice()
      .rangeRound(yRange);

    return {
      x0Scale: x0,
      x1Scale: x1,
      yScale: y,
      xRange: xRange,
      yRange: yRange
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id={this.props.idContainer} style = {{width: 1155 + "px"}}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

module.exports.MultipleBarChart = MultipleBarChart;
```

This component can works receiving data or with data from variable "data" at the beginning of the code. If I run my code taking the data from variable "data", the applications works fine.
[image]

You can see all the bar charts grouped two by two. Please, don't take care about overlaping right now :)

In a log created by you can check that xScale is created correctly because it returns a correct value. You can check it in this in this picture:

[image]

Ok, everything is correct. But, If I comment these lines that you can find in componentWillReceiveProps

```
let scales = this.setScales(data, this.props.keys, this.props.groupKey);
this.setBars(canvas, data, scales, this.props.keys, colors, this.props.lang, this.props.groupKey);
```

And uncomment theses others which are in componentWillReceiveProps too:

```
//this.setBars(canvas, data2, scales, this.props.keys, colors, this.props.lang, this.props.groupKey);
//let scales = this.setScales(data2, this.props.keys);
```

To take the data from props (being received from another component) we've got this result:

[image]

This is due to an erro with xScale, in this log, you can see how it returns undefined:

[image]

This error is returned by this code:

```
let bar = canvas
  .append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    //return "translate(" + scales.x0Scale(d.shoot) + ",0)";
    console.log("d[groupKey]: " + d[groupKey]);
    console.log("scales1: " + scales.x0Scale(d[groupKey]));
    return "translate(" + scales.x0Scale(d[groupKey]) + ",0)";
  });
```

This piece of code you can find it at the beggining of setBars. So, the error is in `return "translate( + scales.X0Scale(d[groupKey]`", 0)"`

But, I don't know why!!! I'm getting me crazy!!! :S

I have been looking for information and I have found that when you create scales you have to assign an array to range and domain functions from Scale, but I have added range funcition giving an array and removing rangeBound from my code and it still doesn't work.

Why works fine when I take data from data variable and works wrong with data from another component? I don't understand anything ...

Comment: Thanks for providing a code example in codesandbox. One remark though: this example would have been much more useful if it contained the problematic code, insted of another version which works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The code is the same. The unique diference is that in CodeSanBox the code comes from a variable and in my application from a previous request to database. Nonetheless, I have adapted my application to get the data from a variable and it works!!! But this same code, when data comes from a previuos query to database doesn't work. I don't understand anything :(((((((((

Comment: Could you update the code sample to show exactly the code which is failing?

Comment: Hi @Mehdi!!! The code is updated!!! If you check it you could see how it is called first setScales and then pass the scale data to setBars. The valid code is not codesandbox , the code valid is what is posted. The differece between them is in codesandox the functions are called in componentDidMount and in the post the funcions are called in componentWillReceiveProps method.

Comment: Well, moving the sample code in codesandbox shows an error telling that `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated. Is this your problem? We can't really help if you don't make the example reproducible - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It doesn't matter if the code is called by componentWillReceiveProps or ComponentDidMount. The problem is happens when we receive data from another component. I have checked that data has been received correctly and to be sure that the format data are correct, before to call any function inside componentWillReceiveProps or ComponentDidMount, I force the transformation to float of all numbers received. The variable data2, has the values formated to float. So, If we use these data to build the graphic we've got the error. If instead of these data we use the data from variable data, it works

Comment: The code works perfectly when we use the data from "data" variable. The problem come up when we use the data from "data2" variable. Values from "data2" variable have been formated to float previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code

Firstly and the most important one

The fact that you see an aggregated bar with data2 is because you do not pass in the groupKeys

When you use

```
this.setBars(canvas, data2, scales, this.props.keys, colors, this.props.lang, this.props.groupKey);
let scales = this.setScales(data2, this.props.keys); // you forgot groupKeys here
```

The correct way would be

```
this.setBars(canvas, data2, scales, this.props.keys, colors, this.props.lang, this.props.groupKey);
let scales = this.setScales(data2, this.props.keys, this.props.groupKeys);
```

Now the other important things to note:

- `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated in the latest version of react and hence you must se `componentDidUpdate` is you need.
- You must never override props like `this.props = nextProps;` as you do in componentWillReceiveProps
- You must not directly implement the update logic within componentDidUpdate as you do now in componentWillReceiveProps. Instead you must compare the previous values with current and only proceed with updatee if it changed
- Now I see that you don't fetch data from a remote resource. If its true, you must not only use `componentDidUpdate` but a combination of both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` and separate out the entire logic in a util function

Your code must look something like

```js
class MultipleBarChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.props = props;
    this.state = {
      loaded: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     if(this.props.data) {
       this.updateChart();
     }
  }

  updateChart = () => {

    console.log("OFFSET_TOP: " + OFFSET_TOP);
    console.log("FFSET_BOTTOM: " + OFFSET_BOTTOM);
    console.log("OFFSET_LEFT: " + OFFSET_LEFT);
    console.log("OFFSET_RIGHT): " + OFFSET_RIGHT);



    let data2 = this.props.data.map((item, index) =>{
      let item2 = {};
      item2.name = item.name;
      item2.ortg = parseFloat(item.ortg).toFixed(2);
      item2.drtg = parseFloat(item.drtg).toFixed(2);
      // console.log("DATA name: " + typeof data[index].name + " PROPS name: " + typeof item2.name);
      // console.log("DATA ortg: " + typeof data[index].ortg.toFixed(2) + " PROPS ortg: " + typeof item2.ortg);     
      // console.log("DATA drtg: " + typeof data[index].drtg.toFixed(2) + " PROPS drtg: " + typeof item2.drtg); 
      return item2;
    });

    let canvas = this.setCanvas();
    let colors = this.setColors();
    let scales = this.setScales(data2, this.props.keys, this.props.groupKey);
    //let scales = this.setScales(data, this.props.keys, this.props.groupKey);
    this.setAxis(canvas, scales);
    this.setLegend(canvas, colors, this.props.keys);
    this.setBars(canvas, data2, scales, this.props.keys, colors, this.props.lang, this.props.groupKey);
    //this.setBars(canvas, data, scales, this.props.keys, colors, this.props.lang, this.props.groupKey);
    this.setState({
      loaded: (typeof data2 !== "undefined" && typeof this.props.keys !== "undefined") ? true : false
    });

  }

  componentDidUpdate(prev){
    const { data, keys, lang, groupKey} = this.props
    if(data !== prev.data || keys !== prev.keys || lang !== prev.lang || groupKey !== prev.groupKey) {
        this.updateChart();
     }
  }

  setAxis(canvas, scales) {
    //x axis
    canvas
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr(
        "transform",
        "translate(" + 0 + ", " + (HEIGHT - OFFSET_TOP - OFFSET_BOTTOM) + ")"
      )
      .call(d3.axisBottom(scales.x0Scale))
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("font-size", "10pt")
      .attr("dx", "-.1em");

    //y axis
    console.log("OFFSET_LEFT: " + OFFSET_LEFT);
    canvas
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      //.call(d3.axisLeft(scales.yScale).ticks(null, ".00%"))
      .call(d3.axisLeft(scales.yScale).tickFormat(d3.format(".2f")))
      //.selectAll("text")
      .style("font-size", "8pt")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + OFFSET_LEFT + ", 0)")
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", OFFSET_LEFT / 2 + 12)
      .attr("y", OFFSET_TOP)
      .attr("dx", "-3em")
      .attr("dy", "-1em")
      .attr("fill", "#FFFFFF")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .style("font-size", "8pt")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(this.props.y_label);

    //return { xAxis: xAxis, yAxis: yAxis };
  }

  setBars(canvas, data, scales, keys, colors, lang, groupKey) {
    let height = HEIGHT - OFFSET_TOP - OFFSET_BOTTOM;
    //var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

    let bar = canvas
      .append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        //return "translate(" + scales.x0Scale(d.shoot) + ",0)";
        console.log("d[groupKey]: " + d[groupKey]);
        console.log("scales1: " + scales.x0Scale(d[groupKey]));
        return "translate(" + scales.x0Scale(d[groupKey]) + ",0)";
      });

    //Here, you append rects to the groups:
    bar
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return keys.map(function(key) {
          return {
            key: key,
            value: d[key]
          };
        });
      })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return scales.x1Scale(d.key);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return scales.yScale(d.value);
      })
      .attr("width", scales.x1Scale.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - scales.yScale(d.value);
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return colors(d.key);
      });

    //Finally, here, you append texts to the groups:
    bar
      .selectAll("text")
      .data(function(d) {
        return keys.map(function(key) {
          return {
            key: key,
            value: d[key]
          };
        });
      })
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("class", "label-multiple-bar")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return scales.x1Scale.bandwidth() * (i + 0.5);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return scales.yScale(d.value) - 5;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return lang === "es"
          ? String(d.value).replace(".", ",") + "%"
          : d.value + "%";
      });
  }

  setCanvas() {
    console.log("WIDTH: " + d3.select("#" + this.props.idContainer).style("width"));
    WIDTH = parseFloat(
      d3.select("#" + this.props.idContainer).style("width")
    ).toFixed(2);
    let svg = d3
      .select("#" + this.props.idContainer)
      .append("svg")
      .style("background-color", "#354560")
      .style("color", "#FFFFFF") //With this we've got the color of the axis too
      .attr("height", HEIGHT)
      .attr("width", WIDTH);

    return svg;
  }

  setColors() {
    return d3
      .scaleOrdinal()
      .range(["#DC3545", "#FFC107", "#007BFF", "#28A745", "#17A2B8", "#cf0eed"]);
  }

  /**
   * Set a legend to the graphic at the top right of it
   *
   * @param {*} canvas
   * @param {*} colors
   * @param {*} keys
   */
  setLegend(canvas, colors, keys) {
    let legend = canvas
      .append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(keys.slice())
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
      });

    legend
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", WIDTH - OFFSET_RIGHT - OFFSET_LEFT)
      .attr("y", 12)
      .attr("width", 25)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .attr("fill", colors);

    legend
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", WIDTH - OFFSET_RIGHT - OFFSET_LEFT + 60)
      .attr("y", 18)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .attr("fill", "#FFFFFF")
      .attr("font-family", "Roboto")
      .style("font-size", "10pt")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end");
  }

  setScales(data, keys, groupKey) {
    let xRange = [OFFSET_LEFT + 0.05, WIDTH - OFFSET_RIGHT];
    let yRange = [HEIGHT - OFFSET_TOP - OFFSET_BOTTOM, OFFSET_TOP];

    let x0 = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(
        data.map(function(d) {
          return d[groupKey];
        })
      )
      .rangeRound(xRange)
      .paddingInner(0.2);

    let x1 = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(keys)
      .rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()])
      .padding(0);

    var y = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([
        0,
        d3.max(data, function(d) {
          return d3.max(keys, function(key) {
            return parseFloat(d[key]);
          });
        })
      ])
      .nice()
      .rangeRound(yRange);

    return {
      x0Scale: x0,
      x1Scale: x1,
      yScale: y,
      xRange: xRange,
      yRange: yRange
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id={this.props.idContainer} style = {{width: 1155 + "px"}}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiplebarchart-5w1s9?file=/src/MultipleBarChart.js)

Comment: It works!!!! I'm totally blind!!! The main problem was the lack of the param groupKey in setScales!!! About not update props, you are right!!! I will update state, thanks!!! About "componentWillReceiveProps" method I'm using it because I'm working with 16.8 version of react and still available. Nonetheless, I will change for ComponentDidUpdate and I will work with it. Thank you very much for your appreciated help!!!